# Disable horizontal swipe with bxslider and enable vertical swipe

Tags: swipe, bxslider

Am using bxlslider for one website with the below setup

```
var aboutSectionSlider = jQuery('.aboutSectionMainSliderInner').bxSlider({ 
mode: 'fade',
controls:false, 
touchEnabled : true,    
captions: false,
pager:'true',
speed: 600, 
pagerSelector : jQuery('.aboutSliderPager'),
onSliderLoad: function(currentIndex){
    jQuery(".aboutSectionSlider").css("visibility", "visible");
    jQuery('.aboutSectionMainSliderInner').children().eq(currentIndex).addClass('activeAboutSlide firstAboutSlide');
},
preventDefaultSwipeX: true,
preventDefaultSwipeY: false
```

});

Per the documentation preventDefaultSwipeX: true should disable horizontal swipe but currently when testing with apple ipad both swiping vertical and horizntal are working. But the swipe did not work properly like when i swipe vertically(top to bottom) down it goes to last slide not the next.

Any idea how to fix this issue?

Comment: Try `mode:vertical,` I would test it but I don't have an ipad handy ATM. BTW, when using a boolean such as `true` or `false`, don't use quotes to be on the safe side. Wrapping quotes around values may be interpreted as a string. Also, I believe the proper syntax for `pagerSelector ` is a selector so: `'.aboutSliderPager'` might be better than `jQuery('.aboutSliderPager')` which is a jQuery Object.

Comment: If `mode::vertical` doesn't work or you don't prefer it, try `oneToOneTouch: false`. One more thing is adjusting `swipeThreshold` since ipads are like oversized phones (dimension-wise that is), so a longer distance may be needed.